# Blocked posts in network tab

Tags: posts, pages

Bit of a brain bender suddenly certain computers on our office network have started to find they are unable to save pagebuilder templates or submit page changes, whenever they do the POST requests seem to get "blocked" or "queued" forever and never move, we use Elementor and are unable to save a template becuase the save button starts the process and it never finishes it, its the same with updating normal pages and posts. Image of the network tab attached below.

[image]

Comment: Is this only a problem on your network? If so, then it's probably best to ask on ServerFault.

Comment: ServerFault? Worth a shot, will go make a Q on there too.

Comment: If you can check your site using a device outside of your office network and it is still an issue, then it may be a problem with WordPress (on-topic) but if the site works everywhere else then ServerFault should be able to help you work out what could be blocking the requests. Worth a quick check of your server access.log and error.log to first see if you get the POSt request, and then if there are any errors you could be missing. make sure to set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php`.